# What is the most effective way to translate string names from database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, translation

I am currently building a small social network with language select.
My problem is what I'm clueless with is i have user groups saved in the database.

```
id  name    
1   Model   
2   Photographer 
3   Makeup artist
```

I select these and place it in to my signup form

```
<div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('group', Lang::get('auth.group'), array("class" => "col-lg-3 control-label ")) }}
            <div class="col-lg-8">
             <select class="col-lg-12" name="group_id[]" id="" multiple size="6" >
                @foreach($groups as $group)
                    <option value="{{ $group->id }}">{{ $group->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
             </select>
            </div>
        </div>
```

But I'm totally clueless how to translate these, I am using `Laravel's Localization`.

Could someone please give me a hint about this?

Comment: Apart from the name for your groups I would alter it to add a new column that will hold a key, i.e.: `group.model`, `group.photographer`... then with Laravel's Localization I will just translate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to localize string that come from your database, then you have to store the keys into your database tables. Then in your views you translate as you will normally do in Laravel.

A database table will have a the following structure (note that apart from the name you will also store a key):

```
-------------------------------------------
| ID | Name          | NameKey            |
===========================================
| 1  | Model         | group.model        |
| 2  | Photographer  | group.photographer |
| 3  | Makeup Artist | group.makeupartist |
-------------------------------------------
```

The name will not me mandatory, but it is useful when the key are not clearly understandable.

Then your view, instead of rendering the *name* you will render the key localized:

```
<option value="{{ $group->id }}">{{ Lang::get($group->nameKey) }}
```

Another suggestions would be using the name itself as the key, but it could problematic when two words that are the same has different meaning in a language, but in another language it is written differently.